# Try to cach UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i'm trying to catch an discord.js error
This error pops up when internet is off, but i want some clean code instead this messy one...

How can i catch this?
I did really try everything..

code:

```
(node:11052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND disc
ordapp.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
 error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
 block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To termin
ate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandl
ed-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejecti
ons_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:11052) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depr
ecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate th
e Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

i did try this at the very top :

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    //console.log('### BIG ONE (%s)', err);
    console.log("555")
    
});
```

aswell this one :

```
client.on('error', error => {


    if (error.code === 'ENOTFOUND') {
        
        console.log(no internet!!)
        
    }
});
```

I also did try this to see where its from, but nothing shows up its still the same

```
try {  
  var err = new Error("my error");  
  Error.stackTraceLimit = infinity;  
  throw err;  
} catch(e) {  
  console.log("Error stack trace limit: ")  
  console.log(Error.stackTraceLimit);  
}
```

```
Error stack trace limit:
10
(node:11008) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND disc
ordapp.com
```

here is the code i use for now what gives the error.
i just want to catch the error in something like this: (No connection)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client({ autoReconnect: true });
const opn = require('opn')
const getJSON = require('get-json')
const request = require('request');
const config = require("./config/config.json");
const pushbullet = require("./config/pushbullet.json");
const addons = require("./config/addons.json");
const Registration = require("./config/Reg.json");



client.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    //console.log('### BIG ONE (%s)', err);
    console.log("555")
    
});



client.login(config.Settings[0].bot_secret_token);
```

Comment: This is a error from one of the promises you're using in your code

Comment: Yes, but i cant figure out wich one...

Comment: yes, that's why you add try/catch or `.catch()` to all promises while writing the code

Comment: I did delete my full code and let the var and const in there but no code at all.. it still gives that error, i know this is happening when there is no internet, because discord cant make connection, i just want to handle it and let it return some custom message instead that whole error

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan see my code, i posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i solved it!!

I put this on top and its all solved.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
    if (error.code === "ENOTFOUND") { console.log ("No internet connection")}
     if (error.code === "ECONNREFUSED") { console.log ("Connection refused")}
    //console.log('Unhandled promise rejection:', error.code);
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to wrap it with try/catch.
And maybe add the following code to understand better what is happening.

```
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_Extensions/Error.stackTraceLimit

Remember to remove it after the problem solved, this is not suitable for production use.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i did do that but nothing pops up different. see edited code